# Report displaying incorrect currency

Tags: reporting-services, printing, reporting

My problem is that when I print some reports from our report server I get the incorrect currency printed. When viewing the report the correct currency(£) is displayed but when that same report is printed from the print button on the SSRS report manager the incorrect currency ($)is shown on the printed page.

Some things to bear in mind:

- We use the RSService to display reports
- All reports language property is set to User!Language
- Both my machine and browser language settings are set to the correct language
- This issue does not happen on all grids on reports(Some reports that have to grids on show correct currency on viewing and then the printed version show one correct and one incorrect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after hours of trying things out it turns out that if you have a text box on a report(or grid cell) that has its language setting set to user!language it will not behave how you expect it to. Hence the reason why I had one grid displaying correct values and another grid displaying incorrect values.

What I did to fix this issue is open up the code view of the report and find and replace < Language>=User!Language< /Language> with and empty string and then only set the reports language setting to User!language.

Hope this saves someone a headache!